# Why is Brad Pitt nominated to academy award as a supporting actor?

Tags: academy-awards, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

I've watched "Once upon a time in Hollywood" and it seems to me that Cliff Booth here is one of two main characters. Why is Brad Pitt nominated as a supporting actor?